# Matching brackets and indentation in RichTextBox using C#?

Tags: c#, text, formatting

I want to make a Code Editing control that can format text somewhat like Visual Studio,till now i have implemented syntax highlighting and autocompletion but i want to format text in nested curly braces.For example:Consider a for loop,

```
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
{
Function_One();              //This should be a tab away from first brace
Function_Two();              //So with this
if(a==b)                     //So with this
{                            //This should be four tabs away from first brace
MessageBox.Show("Some text");//This should be six tabs away from first brace
}                            //This should be four tabs away from first brace
}
```

now what i want is that this should look something like this,

```
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
{
   Function_One();              
   Function_Two();              
   if(a==b)                     
   {                            
      MessageBox.Show("Some text");
   }                            
}
```

I have already tried Regular Expressions but at some point they fail to match,so i tried to match it with code but code cannot match very deeply nested code or is very hard to implement
,so is there any way to achieve this,and one more thing i am doing all this in Winforms control RichTextBox using C#.

Comment: What is your question??

Comment: Way too general, with no code relevant to the actual implementation.

Comment: Also, why would you suddenly want to jump from 2 tabs to 6 tabs on the MessageBox.Show() line?

Comment: I see your edit -- still way to general, still no actual code.

Comment: I don't want to jump from 2 to 6 tabs,i want that much indentation from the first curly brace.

Comment: @user2669188 I don't think you know what a tab is then. Your formatted version has the MessageBox.Show() line only two tabs in from the first curly brace. Also, the brace right above that line you indicate is two tabs in, but the brace right below you indicate is four tabs in. However, your formatted version has them in the same column.

Comment: Want to create Auto Complete Brackets for RichTextBox in C#/VB then go to --  [AutoComplete Brackets In C#.NET/VB .NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f5a10c/auto-complete-brackets-in-C-Sharpvb-net877/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to implement this would be to create some global variables for your form:

```
private int _nestedBracketCount = 0;
private const string TabString = "    ";
private const int TabSpaces = 4;
```

And then handle all of it in a `KeyPressed` event handler for the rich text box:

```
private void richTextBox1_OnKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
    var currentLength = richTextBox1.Text.Length;

    if (e.KeyChar == '{') {
        // need to increment bracket counter
        _nestedBracketCount++;
    } else if (e.KeyChar == '}') {
        // remove last #(TabSpaces) characters from the richtextbox
        richTextBox1.Text.Remove(currentLength - TabSpaces);
        _nestedBracketCount--;
        richTextBox1.AppendText("}");
        e.Handled = true;
    } else if (e.KeyChar == (char)13) {
        // append newline and correct number of tabs.
        var formattedSpaces = string.Empty;
        for (var i = 0; i < _nestedBracketCount; i++)
            formattedSpaces += TabString;
        richTextBox1.AppendText("\n" + formattedSpaces);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I think this should provide you with a halfway decent starting point.

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means a simple feat, I am unaware of any tools or plugins that you would be able to take advantage of, my only recommendation is to research Monodevelop's implementation of this.

See MonoDevelop's [github](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/9e103fcffc8ce0009d1bdc9556cd7977179b446e/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.CodeFormatting/CodeFormatter.cs) for details.